# Integrating mysql database with postgres database using php

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I have my one database in mysql and another in postgres sql.
I have installed moodle in my local machine.Its database is in mysql.
I have to fetch data from mysql databse using service or api and store it in postgres sql using php code.

I fetched the data from mysql databse and prepared a .php file to get contents of the url.
But i don't know how to store them in postgres database.

```
 <?php

   echo "inside new.php file";
   $conn_string = "host=localhost dbname=local user=postgres password=postgres";
   $conn = pg_connect($conn_string) or die('connection failed');
   $homepage = file_get_contents('http://localhost/totara/auth/enlightencrm/manualcron.php?   c=1&m=0&e=0&a=0&p=0');
   echo $homepage;
   if (stristr($homepage,'webners'))
   {
    echo ' Yes, found';
   }
   else
  {
   echo "not found";    
  }
   pg_close($conn);
  ?>
```

please help

Comment: You are coo exciting to the DB but then don't even try to make queries before closing the connection? Also have you considered using PDO so at least you have a single DB extension to work with both dbs?

Answer (score 0):

The same like mysql queries but using `pg_*` functions instead of `mysqli_*`. For example:

```
$conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=publisher");
$query = "UPDATE authors SET author=UPPER(author) WHERE id=1;";    
pg_query($conn, $query);
```

List of available php postgres functions you can find [here](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pgsql.php).

**UPD.**

```
// Your data looks like this
$data = array(
    1 => (object) array(
        'id' => 1, 
        'category' => 0,
        'sortorder' => 1,
        'fullname' => 'webners',
        'shortname' => 'webners',
        'idnumber' => '',
        'summary' => '> 3'
    ),
    'summaryformat' => 0,
    'format' => 'site',
    'showgrades' => 1,
    'newsitems' => 3
);

// get needed and convert object to array
$arrayRowData = (array) $data[1];

// Build query.
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (id, category, sortorder, fullname, shortname, idnumber, summary) VALUES (
    ' . $arrayRowData['id'] . ',
    ' . $arrayRowData['category'] . ',
    ' . $arrayRowData['sortorder'] . ',
    "' . $arrayRowData['fullname'] . '",
    "' . $arrayRowData['shortname'] . '",
    "' . $arrayRowData['idnumber'] . '",
    "' . $arrayRowData['summary'] . '"
);';
```

Comment: I have to enter the contents coming from the url into my database.
My content is

Comment: Or if you use PDO, you can use the same interface pretty much, just a different driver.

Comment: I have to enter the contents coming from the url into my database.
My content isArray
([1] => stdClass Object
 (
[id] => 1
[category] => 0
[sortorder] => 1
[fullname] => webners
[shortname] => webners
[idnumber] => 
[summary] => > 3
            )
[summaryformat] => 0
[format] => site
[showgrades] => 1
[newsitems] => 3
            )                                                           Firstly i have to remove std object so that it will be converted into array..Can you suggest how can i do it.?

Comment: @user2978605 First of all, you need to create table for this data in your postgres. Next, just run `INSERT` by `pg_query`. SQL syntax is nearly the same like in MySQL.

Comment: I have created a table in postgres.I have to insert above data into my table with same field name.Can you suggest me the query.

Comment: @user2978605 see UPD section.

Comment: Be careful about SQL-injection! This INSERT-statement is a potential security issue. Escape your content before putting it in a query or use prepared statements (even better).

Comment: I tried this but got INSERT INTO table (id, category, sortorder, fullname, shortname, idnumber, summary) VALUES ( , , , "", "", "", "" ); ....I think the $homepage is coming in the form of string.